# The break statement not working and adds an additional System.out.print;

Tags: java

I want to stop the System.out.print( num + " + " ) after 495 since it kept on going after the number 500

```java
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num = 0, sum = 0;

        while (sum <= 25250) {
            if (num == 500)
                break;

            num = num + 5;

            sum = sum + num;
   
            System.out.print( num + " + " );
        }

        System.out.print( " = " + sum);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: The `+` after the number will always be printed. There is no condition which prevents that.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. the break is working fine. you should add "+" when the second or other number is present. Inserted of just inserting every time. put if(num==5) in your code and see output. you will understand

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int num = 0, sum = 0;

   while (sum <= 27250){

       if (num == 500)
            break;
       if(num!=0) System.out.print("+ ");
       num = num + 5;
       sum = sum + num;
       System.out.print( num +" " );    
    }

  System.out.print( " = " + sum);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I've been stuck trying to figure it out for a while

Answer (score 0):

Move the break after the point where you increase `num` value statement.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int num = 0, sum = 0;

    while (sum <= 25250){
        num += 5;
       
        if (num == 495){
            System.out.print(num);
            sum = sum + num;
            break;
        }
       
        if (num == 500){
        break;}

        sum = sum + num;

        System.out.print( num + " + " );
    }

    System.out.print( " = " + sum);
}
```

I also went ahead and added a point that removes the plus, just to make the formatting work.